# Why is numpy save not immediate, and can it be forced to save immediately?

Tags: numpy, save

I thought this question would have been asked already, but I can't find it, so here goes: I've noticed that numpy.save commands only trigger, i.e. the file to-be-created is actually created, after the entire code has finished running. This is bad when the code takes days or weeks to run, and I want to pin down exactly which function, and what arguments into the function, are causing the bottleneck.

There is a similar issue with the print() command; it doesn't write to the output file immediately but rather waits until the entire code is finished before writing. I can force it to write immediately with this code:

```
def printnow(*messages):
    w=open("output.log","a")
    for message in messages:
        w.write(str(message))
        w.write(" ")
    w.write("\n")
    w.close()
```

I was wondering whether it's possible to do an analogous thing, i.e. force an immediate save, for numpy arrays. No need for appending; overwriting with the current value of the numpy array is fine.

If it makes a difference, I'm not running the code on my personal computer but a group server, which I issue commands to and check on using Putty and WinSCP.

Thanks

Edit: I tried another package, shelve, and it encounters the same problem. I create a global variable called `function_calls` and initialize it to 0. Then, at the start of the function that I suspect is causing the bottleneck, I put in the following code:

```
global function_calls
file='function_inputs'+str(function_calls)
function_shelf=shelve.open(file,'n')
for key in dir():
    function_shelf[key]=locals()[key]
function_calls+=1
```

This code is intended to create a new file that saves the function inputs, each time the function is called. Unfortunately, 9 hours into starting the run, no files have been created. So I suspect Python is just waiting until the whole run is finished before creating the files I asked it to.

Comment: FYI: For the `print()` function, you could try adding the parameter `flush=True`.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an instance of a common Python issue in writing files: unless you close them immediately, they may not be flushed and closed until the process exits, or the file reference is garbage collected.

A common cause would be the process shutting down in an unplanned way (crash in interpreter or library).

This can be hard to prevent when passing a file *name* into an API call. Many APIs allow passing in a file *object* instead, which allows the user to manage this more tightly. An example:

```
    import os
    import numpy as np
    # Make some data
    a = np.random.random((100,100))
    # Open the output file in a context manager
    with open("test.npy","wb") as outf:
        np.save(outf, a)
    # We've already flushed and closed the file
    # Reopen, load, and prove it succeeded
    with open("test.npy","rb") as inf:
        b = np.load(inf)
    difference = abs(a-b).sum()
    os.unlink("test.npy")
    assert difference == 0.0, "Usually a lossless serialization"
    print("Ok!")
```

This just bit me in *someone else's code* using np.save, and can happen in PIL, when saving an image (I have the scars).